# Saving Matplotlib animation gives: AttributeError: Figure.show works only for figures managed by pyplot, normally created by pyplot.figure()

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I was trying to save an animation of this plot, but don't know why I get this error:
AttributeError: Figure.show works only for figures managed by pyplot, normally created by pyplot.figure()

Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import time

from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

global ax, fig, G
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
G = nx.DiGraph()

def showNet(n):
    global ax, fig, G

    plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
    
    fig.clf()    

    l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7 = n[0], n[1], n[2], n[3], n[4], n[5], n[6] 

    edgelist= [(l1,l2),(l2,l3), (l3,l4), (l3,l5), (l4, l1), (l5, l6), (l5, l7)]

    pos = {l1: (10, 60), l2: (10, 40), l3:(80, 40), l4:(140, 60), l5:(200, 20), l6:(250, 40), l7:(250,10)}
    
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, nodelist=list(pos.keys()), node_size=2000, alpha=0.8) 
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edgelist= edgelist , edge_color="gray", arrows=True, arrowsize=10, arrowstyle='wedge') 

    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos, labels=dict(zip(pos.keys(),pos.keys())),  font_color="black") 

    plt.grid(False)

    plt.ion() 
    fig.show() 
    plt.pause(0.0000001)

def update(i):
    n = random.sample(range(1, 10), 7)
    showNet(n)
    
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update)

#here is where I fail:
ani.save('video.mp4')
```

the code is working fine, it's until trying "ani.save('video.mp4') that I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your `ffmpeg` path.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = 'your/path/to/ffmpeg'
```

Comment: nop!! that didn't work, instead, it gave me another error message plus the previous one: IndexError: list index out of range